# Данные меняются в двух стейтах одновременно

Tags: javascript, reactjs, table, react-hook, state

Я пытаюсь сделать таблицу с редактируемыми полями. Идея в том, что при нажатии на кнопку save данные из инпута должны сохраняться в таблице, а при нажатии на кнопку cancel данные в таблице не должны меняться. У меня проблема со стейтами contacts и contactsInput. Первый стейт нужен для того, чтобы выводить данные в таблицу. Второй для поля value в . При записи данных в один стейт, происходит запись и в другой стейт. Хотя, насколько я понимаю, общих ссылок у них нет. Заранее спасибо!

import React, {Fragment, useState} from 'react'

export default function ContentTable() {

```
const data = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "fullName": "Jenny Chan",
        "address": "3 waterfoot road",
        "phoneNumber": "333-962-7516",
        "email": "jenny.chan@email.com"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "fullName": "Jessica warren",
        "address": "4 tall town",
        "phoneNumber": "011-211-7516",
        "email": "jessica.warren@email.com"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "fullName": "Tony Frank",
        "address": "11 lesly road",
        "phoneNumber": "788-962-7516",
        "email": "tony.frank@email.com"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "fullName": "Jeremy Clark",
        "address": "333 miltown manor",
        "phoneNumber": "011-962-111",
        "email": "jeremy.clark@email.com"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "fullName": "Raymond Edwards",
        "address": "99 blue acres",
        "phoneNumber": "3231-962-7516",
        "email": "raymon.edwards@email.com"
    }
]

const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([...data])
const [contactsInput, setContactsInput] = useState([...data])
const [checkId, setCheckId] = useState(null)

const handleChange = (index) => (
    (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        const {name, value} = event.target
        const contactsInputCopy = [...contactsInput]
        contactsInputCopy[index][name] = value
        console.log('\ncontacts:', contacts[index][name])
        console.log('contactsInput:', contactsInput[index][name])
        setContactsInput(contactsInputCopy)
    }
)

const handleSave = () => {
    setContacts([...contactsInput])
    setCheckId(null)
}

const handleCancel = (event) => {
    setCheckId(null)
}

return (
    <div className="tableContainer">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                    <th>Phone number</th>
                    <th>email</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {contacts.map((contact, index) => (
                <Fragment key={`key:${index}`}>
                    {checkId === contact.id ? (
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="fullName" value={contactsInput[index].fullName} onChange={handleChange(index)}/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="address" value={contactsInput[index].address} onChange={handleChange(index)}/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="phoneNumber" value={contactsInput[index].phoneNumber} onChange={handleChange(index)}/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="email" value={contactsInput[index].email} onChange={handleChange(index)}/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="button" value="Save" onClick={handleSave}/>
                                <input type="button" value="Cancel" onClick={handleCancel}/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    ) : (
                        <tr>
                            <td>{contact.fullName}</td>
                            <td>{contact.address}</td>
                            <td>{contact.phoneNumber}</td>
                            <td>{contact.email}</td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="button" value="Edit" onClick={() => setCheckId(contact.id)}/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    )}
                </Fragment>
            ))}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
)
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оператор `...` подходит только для копирования массивов, состоящих из простых типов. Так как элементы массива `data` это объекты, то `[...data]` не создает новый массив.